# Microsoft Application Registration Portal. Redirect URI editing failure

Tags: office365

I'm developing Outlook Application and using this tutorial as example:
https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted/Tutorial/php

Application created by https://apps.dev.microsoft.com.
But I have an trouble to save any platform URL but one that starts with 'http://localhost/'

Is there some king of URL validation microsoft did?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing protocol to **https** solved the issue.

---

Obviously, Microsoft should either return appropriate error message or add hint about URI restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

You can just edit the application manifest and add what ever you want.

1- At the bottom of the application page click on the **"Edit Application Manifest"**
[image]

2- add the links under **"replyUrls"** as the following:

[image]